# How to broadcast message to clients of the certain namespace in Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is a sample from socket.io website:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('a message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
    chat.emit('a message', {
        everyone: 'in'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
  });

var news = io
  .of('/news')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('item', { news: 'item' });
  });
```

normally I use io.sockets.emit(...) to broadcast data to the clients. But how to broadcast messages to clients connected with namespace? In other words how to send message to all clients subscribed to news, and not to those who subscribed to chat?

UPDATE:
I guess I know the answer:

```
news.sockets.emit(...);
```

am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. BTW, you are allowed to post answers to your own questions and accept them, according to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), so that your question doesn't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

From an official [example on github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('justin bieber fans');
  socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
  io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
});
```

So if you want to send a message to all the connected clients in a namespace you can use `io.sockets.in('namespace').emit('message')`.

Comment: Your example works, but the example on github doesn't say how the client can differentiate between messages from different channels. The method in the Q does allow this.

Comment: Ok, I need to have two different streams over one socket connection. So from client side I call **io.connect('IP:PORT/NAMESPACE')** And on the server side I need to send messages separately for each namespace.

Comment: So in your example how do I know to which namespace to **join** the socket?

Comment: Checkout http://socket.io/#how-to-use on the bottom of the page, the example after 'Restricting yourself to a namespace.'

Comment: @alessioalex by using `join` and `in` you are talking about `rooms` not `namesapces`: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Comment: @Mahdi yes probably the naming has changed since I've posted this answer :D

Comment: @alessioalex I guess so! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following:

```
io.of('/news').emit('data', data);
```

In my case it works(version `"socket.io":"^1.0.0-pre2"`).